# SSRS Dataset refresh fields not working, but the query can be ran through query designer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dynamic SQL procedure that is a data source in SSRS. When I click refresh fields nothing happens. However when I run via query designer and pass in the required parameters the query returns the expected rows.

The query doesn't run without these parameters. I suspect refresh fields is not passing through the parameters? Is there a fix for this?

I've tried hard coding the parameters in the data source but that has not worked and it is still not returning the fields.
I've also deleted the .data files

Comment: What do you mean by a "dynamic SQL procedure"? Give us an example.

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/

Comment: An example within your question please. Are you literally calling `exec` within your SSRS datasource? If so my guess it that it is unable to determine what the returned columns are. When you add a non-dynamic query it is able to generate the list of columns, but with dynamic SQL it might not be able to do that. Potentially the fix is to move the dynamic SQL within a stored procedure and then have the procedure return the list of columns without having to run the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the data source from

[image: 1]

to

[image: 2]

This now passes through the required parameters when refreshing fields

Comment: There is nothing dynamic about that? Why did you link to an article about dynamic SQL? This is just calling a static stored procedure.

Comment: It is a dynamic sql query https://imgur.com/a/EOAVXdk

Comment: Yeah, inside your procedure, but there is nothing dynamic in SSRS

Comment: @DaleK yes that's why i said dynamic sql procedure in my question